# DelphiVCL for Python forms don't minimize when I use the border icon of the window

Tags: python, delphi, vcl

As I use DelphiVCL for Python where I don't have Delphi installed I stepped on an issue with the forms. The apps work as expected except the fact that the form doesn't minimize when I press the minimize border icon of the form. It is normal or only on the computers I use have this behavior. I'm using Python 3.10 on Windows 10.
Later edit:
Here is the sample code:

```
from delphivcl import *

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "Template Python GUI Delphi VCL"
    app = Form(Application)
    app.SetProps(Caption = "Welcome")
    app.Show()
    FreeConsole()
    Application.Run()
    app.Destroy()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not about the code, it's about GUI. I will provide code in an edit.

Comment: It was discussed here: https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiVCL4Python/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code to your `def main()` function:

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskBar = True
```

Once you've added that code, then the minimize window button will work as expected. `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar` is set to `False` by default and need to manually be set to `True`